# Transferring Wordpress website hosted on Google App Engine to another Hosting

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have a wordpress powered website that is hosted on Google App Engine. Recently, my harddisk blew up , so my local copy of it (required to install plugins etc) is gone. However, there was an option to download the entire App Engine project , which I did.

I would like to run that app engine project locally (I need to disable google App engine related plugins so that the same website may be hosted on another hosting )

I installed memcached module for php, uploaded the database, but now I get this error:

> Warning: require_once(google/appengine/api/urlfetch_service_pb.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/tcmotors/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/modules/urlfetch.php on
>   line 72
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'google/appengine/api/urlfetch_service_pb.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/tcmotors/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/modules/urlfetch.php on
>   line 72

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that it's trying to load files contained in the root of the google app engine install, and they aren't found (because you are no longer on google app engine). You should try checking out the specific files/lines the error messages indicate (/var/www/tcmotors/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/modules/urlfetch.php on line 72). There should be either an include statement or a function being used on those lines that references the missing files. By commenting out that line, and any subsequent error lines, you will lose some functionality, but it should no longer fatal error. Then you will be able to install the plugins.